# Get filename of failed uploaded file in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, validation, file-upload

How do I get the filename of failed uploaded file and pass it on validation error message? For example: "The **file.0** must be 1024 kilobytes." be like "The **failed-file-sample.jpg** must be 1024 kilobytes."

Here's the sample code arrangement:

```
$messages = [
    'mimes' => 'File(s) must be of type: :values.',
    'size'   => 'The ' .  $request->file('file_field')->getClientOriginalName() . ' must be :size kilobytes.'
];

$this->validate(
    request(), 
    ['file_field' => 'bail|required|mimes:gif,jpg,jpeg,png|size:1024'], 
    $messages
);
```

Comment: just use  $request->file_field_name->getClientOriginalName(); if you are using validation just put this line before validation

Comment: @SalmanZafar - you mean like $request->file('file_field_name')->getClientOriginalName()? its not working. sorry i'm new to this

Comment: both will work. you can use anyone of them.$request->file('file_field_name')->getClientOriginalName(); or $request->file_field_name->getClientOriginalName();

Comment: oh! its working for single file upload. but if multiple file upload, it returns FatalThrowableError... i also edited my orig post to show a bit codes

Comment: use foreach loop for multiple images

Comment: @SalmanZafar Thank for the help!

Comment: @SalmanZafar sorry, i'm confuse. how do you loop through and get the filenames then mass to custom error message?

Comment: May be this can help you without using foreach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727463/how-to-do-validation-for-multiple-images-upload-in-laravel-5-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$validationArray = [];
foreach ($request->file('file_field') as $key => $file) {
    $validationArray['file_field.'.$key.'.size'] => 'The ' .  $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' must be 1024 kilobytes.'; 
}
$messages = [
    'file_field.*.mimes' => 'File(s) must be of type: :values.',
     $validationArray
];
$this->validate(
    $request, 
    [
        'file_field' => 'bail|required|array',
         'file_field.*' => 'mimes:gif,jpg,jpeg,png|size:1024'
    ], 
$messages);
```

Comment: this giving me "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array"

Comment: i updated your answer. now my validation is working... thanks!

Comment: How this answer is correct, it is showing me `=>` syntax error

Comment: Also in place of filename showing `uploads.0`